# How to Dynamically Change the Label of a Virtual Thermostat in Google Home Playground?

Tags: google-home, google-smart-home

I'm currently working with a virtual thermostat device in the Google Home Playground(https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/playground). My goal is to dynamically change the display label of the thermostat (currently set to 'Indoor') based on certain conditions or settings.

[image]

**Context:**

- The thermostat is a virtual device from the Google Home Playground.
- I am not using any physical devices or third-party apps.
- My objective is to have the 'Indoor' label change depending on specific settings or states.
- There are no issues with the current functionality; this is intended as an enhancement.

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to dynamically change the label of a virtual thermostat in the Google Home Playground? If so, how can this be achieved?

**What I have tried:**
I've explored the standard device types and traits in the [Google Smart Home documentation](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/concepts/devices-traits) but found no clear method for implementing dynamic label changes in the Playground environment.

**Specific Concerns:**

- Understanding the limitations of the Google Home Playground regarding dynamic UI changes.
- Insights into how such changes are managed in a fully implemented smart home action, outside of the Playground environment.

I appreciate any guidance or references that can point me in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'indoor' label is hardcoded value and cannot be dynamically changed based on specific settings or states whether on a virtual or physical Nest Thermostat. It refers to the indoor temperature settings.